# NumPy - fast stable arg-sort of large array by frequency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, frequency

I have large 1D [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array `a` of any comparable `dtype`, some of its elements may be repeated.

How do I find sorting indexes `ix` that will stable-sort (stability in [a sense described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64238462/941531)) `a` by frequencies of values in descending/ascending orders?

I want to find fastest and simplest way to do this. Maybe there is existing standard numpy function to do that.

There is another related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737245/how-to-sort-a-numpy-array-by-frequency) but it was asking specifically to remove arrays duplicates, i.e. output only unique sorted values, I need all values of original array including duplicates.

I've coded my first trial to do the task, but it is not the fastest (uses Python's loop) and probably not shortest/simplest possible form. This python loop can be very expensive if repeating of equal elements is not high and array is huge. Also would be nice to have short function for doing this all if available in NumPy (e.g. imaginary `np.argsort_by_freq()`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHNSgMxEL7nKQY8dAKxVq0KhR4EH8FbkRJ3s@3Q3UmabLD15eukQYuge9gk8/3km0w4jlvP96cTDcHHETgP4Qg2AQfFYRott36YJudavNVqSwbYQOtSA0t4MnA3N/Aas1NWzhd@s/XUOJSClcrG4Za0AWQj/yBMVCBfb4f31p4LF2ldUBRG64WANxCmKQ@olUatVU4GmlQlmWmfHVoD0Y058rrxmccClkxa2a7yPl30CUvw8RhcrRGPj3OtOh8hiyMQwycFrPZ6cQ5ou5X0tYT8JppGUXfuvGJ0qD42bpI8HF7bzsCOuJXyJI32vXcTDVfwIgrHLfEGCk@5Prm/Hf4xeP6tD1GS4yT6j7QAko57nGl5JB9pQ2z7tZVBybmLbp/wrmyLzrUC3OuJ/jYoCX6gSp5/k@WyNR3w4UKXmBKp2WGd3GWwLBOV9y/Z7YoOb2VbVzoYJeBMZnY6fQE)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
hi, n, desc = 7, 24, True
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(hi), (n,), p = (
    lambda p = np.random.random((hi,)): p / p.sum()
)())
us, cs = np.unique(a, return_counts = True)
af = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.int64)
for u, c in zip(us, cs):
    af[a == u] = c
if desc:
    ix = np.argsort(-af, kind = 'stable') # Descending sort
else:
    ix = np.argsort(af, kind = 'stable') # Ascending sort
print('rows: i_col(0) / original_a(1) / freqs(2) / sorted_a(3)')
print('    / sorted_freqs(4) / sorting_ix(5)')
print(np.stack((
    np.arange(n), a, af, a[ix], af[ix], ix,
), 0))
```

outputs:

```
rows: i_col(0) / original_a(1) / freqs(2) / sorted_a(3)
    / sorted_freqs(4) / sorting_ix(5)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [ 1  1  1  1  3  0  5  0  3  1  1  0  0  4  6  1  3  5  5  0  0  0  5  0]
 [ 7  7  7  7  3  8  4  8  3  7  7  8  8  1  1  7  3  4  4  8  8  8  4  8]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  5  5  5  5  3  3  3  4  6]
 [ 8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  1  1]
 [ 5  7 11 12 19 20 21 23  0  1  2  3  9 10 15  6 17 18 22  4  8 16 13 14]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: @Nick I wrote reasons above: 1) It is not fastest (uses pure-python loop) 2) maybe not shortest 3) and important not stable ([in this sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64238462/941531)) for descending order, but stability I just solved a minute ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64238562/941531).

Comment: So what would be your expected output for this question in descending order?

Comment: @Nick In the very last output example I need at the end of 3-th row `4 6` instead of `6 4` as they both have same frequency and they go in order `4 6` in original array. But stability is not the problem, I solved it already like in comment above, just to argsort negated values. I'll fix my question not to bother people about stability. What is important is that I want fastest solution (without Python loops) and shortest if possible.

Comment: @Nick If array is huge and few elements are repeated in it then this Python loop will take very long time.

Comment: Using a `Counter` and normal python sort as I've suggested in my answer should be much faster...

Comment: @Nick Thanks! But still counter would be quite slow for handling numpy large data. Especially if level of repeating of elements is low, i.e. almost all are unique. Although might be faster than my python loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured myself probably very fast solution for any dtype using just numpy functions without python looping, it works in `O(N log N)` time. Used numpy functions: `np.unique`, `np.argsort` and array indexing.

Although wasn't asked in original question, I implemented extra flag `equal_order_by_val` if it is False then array elements with same frequencies are sorted as equal stable range, meaning that there could be `c  d  d  c  d  c` output like in outputs dumps below, because this is the order as elements go in original array for equal frequency. When flag is True such elements are in addition sorted by value of original array, resulting in `c  c  c  d  d  d`. In other words in case of False we sort stably just by key `freq`, and when it is True we sort by `(freq, value)` for ascending order and by `(-freq, value)` for descending order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNj9owEL3nV1jaQ2w1Tbv0S0LbW9VeK7U3iiKTTGDAsYM/EPTP07EdyK66voDfzJuZN34ZL35n9IfrFYfRWM@ct6i3FRuk3xUTpsMwXph0TI@FHmsrdWeG2gF0/L0oigf2AzRY6YnIUI/Bs056WRQ7rJiuWAeuZV/Zl4otPlXstw1QKPAerCOU6klr5YUrdJ7n7rV0LWIzJQmq4C8j5GSz2UPrG7Fa7nBdyAxOE7U7gy3wiVcxrisij5TDC0ZHyWHTyQTMpPzDb6za4V@ohFhS2js21i4MXBSCCxLaG8vgGKRqjO3ANptLc5KKJLPVd6kcZHHrZWr2wH4ZdYor8dIdioQFGirQUtpJedB4DMBlxSz4YHWD@kQzRKmx0h1uTdDeTahIpWRP19atAm0h3h09VHOAC6FvKYZ9XjvQWJSbUgj7f/o8bKqww943G0yNBnnmj9kFdQuoePqnzJaHvCJB27ljCyHEXGeehPPbhZ40viEn0aj954@CPT096yjYmzs/nuQKqbdwa/fCA7lClJ674vlmpG3sd29asQPqjmKl83KjoBT0Kt9MmjB51TtQfTE910@yXoItuKC8y/gYUV7@0a@srqxeWWgeKVpFy4Hmvjnkro@XSA@qiDyr1IKMShFjcYuaKkoKS1E9I/UWji6ifUydDy@jHOgyZYXn9QvaFJzZOWOKkNwGz4TjeWKtZ0Nk6VFFbfeBvs7HBRFLVtZ7g5qv6GPlIKbYQiTNELWS5DUZ4nr9Bw)

```
import string, math
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# Generating input data

hi, n, desc = 7, 25, True
letters = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters), dtype = np.object_)[:hi]
a = np.random.choice(letters, (n,), p = (
    lambda p = np.random.random((letters.size,)): p / p.sum()
)())

for equal_order_by_val in [False, True]:
    # Solving task

    us, ui, cs = np.unique(a, return_inverse = True, return_counts = True)
    af = cs[ui]
    sort_key = -af if desc else af
    if equal_order_by_val:
        shift_bits = max(1, math.ceil(math.log(us.size) / math.log(2)))
        sort_key = ((sort_key.astype(np.int64) << shift_bits) +
            np.arange(us.size, dtype = np.int64)[ui])
    ix = np.argsort(sort_key, kind = 'stable') # Do sorting itself

    # Printing results

    print('\nequal_order_by_val:', equal_order_by_val)
    for name, val in [
        ('i_col', np.arange(n)),  ('original_a', a),
        ('freqs', af),            ('sorted_a', a[ix]),
        ('sorted_freqs', af[ix]), ('sorting_ix', ix),
    ]:
        print(name.rjust(12), ' '.join([str(e).rjust(2) for e in val]))
```

outputs:

```
equal_order_by_val: False
       i_col  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
  original_a  g  g  c  f  d  d  g  a  a  a  f  f  f  g  f  c  f  a  e  b  g  d  c  b  f
       freqs  5  5  3  7  3  3  5  4  4  4  7  7  7  5  7  3  7  4  1  2  5  3  3  2  7
    sorted_a  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  g  g  g  g  g  a  a  a  a  c  d  d  c  d  c  b  b  e
sorted_freqs  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  5  5  5  5  5  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  1
  sorting_ix  3 10 11 12 14 16 24  0  1  6 13 20  7  8  9 17  2  4  5 15 21 22 19 23 18

equal_order_by_val: True
       i_col  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
  original_a  g  g  c  f  d  d  g  a  a  a  f  f  f  g  f  c  f  a  e  b  g  d  c  b  f
       freqs  5  5  3  7  3  3  5  4  4  4  7  7  7  5  7  3  7  4  1  2  5  3  3  2  7
    sorted_a  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  g  g  g  g  g  a  a  a  a  c  c  c  d  d  d  b  b  e
sorted_freqs  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  5  5  5  5  5  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  1
  sorting_ix  3 10 11 12 14 16 24  0  1  6 13 20  7  8  9 17  2 15 22  4  5 21 19 23 18
```

Comment: @Nick it is not sorted by value but by frequency key which is row `sorted_freqs`. `c` and `d` just have same frequency. And for same frequency stable order (same as in original array) should be done by initial task.

Comment: Ah, that is not how my code works. It will sort all the `c`s before all the `d`s because the first `c` occurs before the first `d`. I've added another (simpler) solution which sorts the same way as your code

Comment: @Nick Stop, don't update. That's a good point BTW. Although initial task was not about this but it is good to implement in my and your code as extra flag. Basically if some flag like  `equal_freqs_sort_by_value = True` then same frequencies should be separated too by sorting by value then. I.e. sorting with this flag should be by tuples `(freq, a_val)` not just by `freq`.

Comment: I just added another solution. The original code is still there, it would be reasonably easy to merge the two solutions with a flag to control the operation.

Comment: The straight python solution is about 3x faster: https://ideone.com/gp4DVj

Comment: @Nick That's because you measured thousands of iterations of processing same small input, but for my case (of huge data) you should measure arrays with millions of elements and just in one run taking seconds. At least I meant to solve the task for supporting very large inputs. For small inputs definitely Python always wins, same like in my other question with `np.searchsorted` when converting numpy array to tuples gave higher performance for keys below length of 100.

Comment: You're right - using a list of 1000000 random numbers your method is ~3x faster.

Comment: @Nick If I have data in numpy array always which is like in my case, not in list, then it will be even more than `3x` faster, from-list conversion is definitely taking lots of time too.

Comment: @Nick Also when I have quite many repetitions of elements in my data like in my case my method could be even faster because one of main slow down happens when there are many unique elements.

Comment: Thanks to help of @Divakar simplified/speeded-up algorithm by removing `np.searchsorted()` use in favor of using feature/argument `return_inverse` of `np.unique()`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but it seems that with a `Counter` you can then sort the indexes of each element according to the count of that element's value, using the element value and then the index to break ties. For example:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  0,  5,  0,  3,  1,  1,  0,  0,  4,  6,  1,  3,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0]
counts = Counter(a)

t = [(counts[v], v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a)]
t.sort()
print([v[2] for v in t])
t.sort(reverse=True)
print([v[2] for v in t])
```

Output:

```
[13, 14, 4, 8, 16, 6, 17, 18, 22, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 15, 5, 7, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 23]
[23, 21, 20, 19, 12, 11, 7, 5, 15, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 22, 18, 17, 6, 16, 8, 4, 14, 13]
```

If you want to maintain ascending order of indexes with groups with equal counts, you can just use a lambda function for the descending sort:

```
t.sort(key = lambda x:(-x[0],-x[1],x[2]))
print([v[2] for v in t])
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 15, 6, 17, 18, 22, 4, 8, 16, 14, 13]
```

If you want to maintain the ordering of elements in the order that they originally appeared in the array *if their counts are the same*, then rather than sort on the values, sort on the index of their first occurrence in the array:

```
a = [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  0,  5,  0,  3,  1,  1,  0,  0,  4,  6,  1,  3,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0]
counts = Counter(a)

idxs = {}
t = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if not v in idxs:
        idxs[v] = i
    t.append((counts[v], idxs[v], i))

t.sort()
print([v[2] for v in t])
t.sort(key = lambda x:(-x[0],x[1],x[2]))
print([v[2] for v in t])
```

Output:

```
[13, 14, 4, 8, 16, 6, 17, 18, 22, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 15, 5, 7, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 23]
[5, 7, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 15, 6, 17, 18, 22, 4, 8, 16, 13, 14]
```

To sort according to count, and then position in the array, you don't need the value or the first index at all:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  0,  5,  0,  3,  1,  1,  0,  0,  4,  6,  1,  3,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0]
counts = Counter(a)

t = [(counts[v], i) for i, v in enumerate(a)]
t.sort()
print([v[1] for v in t])
t.sort(key = lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
print([v[1] for v in t])
```

This produces the same output as the prior code for the sample data, for your string array:

```
a = ['g',  'g',  'c',  'f',  'd',  'd',  'g',  'a',  'a',  'a',  'f',  'f',  'f',
     'g',  'f',  'c',  'f',  'a',  'e',  'b',  'g',  'd',  'c',  'b',  'f' ]
```

This produces the output:

```
[18, 19, 23, 2, 4, 5, 15, 21, 22, 7, 8, 9, 17, 0, 1, 6, 13, 20, 3, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 24]
[3, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 24, 0, 1, 6, 13, 20, 7, 8, 9, 17, 2, 4, 5, 15, 21, 22, 19, 23, 18]
```

Comment: I need specifically solution for NumPy when array is huge. It should be very fast for this case. And using even standard library's Counter is probably slow as it refers to python objects like `int` or `str`.

Comment: If number of unique elements in original array is not much less than number of all elements (i.e. repeating level is low) then counter solution or python loop all will be slow.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a speed comparison of your solution with this.

Comment: @Arty I've also added another version of the code which I think achieves the stability you were looking for.

Comment: I'm almost sure even without measurement that your solution should be faster than mine for the case of almost unique elements. But still more efficient numpy-oriented vectorized solution is probably what I want. BTW, Counter can be used for any type of elements including any comparable types like `str`?

Comment: This construct `idxs = [a.index(v) for v in a]` is probably very-very slow, as `.index()` linearly scans whole array so complexity is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @Arty yes, a counter can count any hashable object.

Comment: @Arty I've rewritten that to not use `index`, it only requires one iteration over the array.

Comment: I just figured very fast only-numpy-funcs solution myself [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64239350/941531) with `O(N log N)` complexity using `np.searchsorted`.