# NumPy - descending stable arg-sort of arrays of any dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, stable-sort

NumPy's [np.argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is able to do [stable sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) through passing `kind = 'stable'` argument.

Also `np.argsort` doesn't support reverse (descending) order.

If non-stable behavior is needed then descending order can be easily modeled through `desc_ix = np.argsort(a)[::-1]`.

I'm looking for efficient/easy solution to descending-stable-sort NumPy's array `a` of any comparable `dtype`. See my meaning of "stability" in the last paragraph.

For the case when `dtype` is any numerical then stable descending arg-sorting can be easily done through sorting negated version of array:

```
print(np.argsort(-np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), kind = 'stable'))
# prints: array([3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

But I need to support any comparable `dtype` including `np.str_` and `np.object_`.

Just for clarification - maybe for descending orders classical meaning of `stable` means that equal elements are enumerated right to left. If so then in my question meaning of `stable + descending` is something different - equal ranges of elements should be enumerated left to right, while equal ranges between each other are ordered in descending order. I.e. same behavior should be achieved like in the last code above. I.e. I want stability in a sense same like Python achieves in next code:

```
print([e[0] for e in sorted(enumerate([1,2,2,3,3,3]), key = lambda e: e[1], reverse = True)])
# prints: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this formula should work:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
s = len(a) - 1 - np.argsort(a[::-1], kind='stable')[::-1]
print(s)
# [3 4 5 1 2 0]
```

Comment: Great! Seems to work, at least for several tested by me cases. Maybe we can we prove correctness of this formula somehow. So far fastest/best solution to my mind! @Divakar

Comment: @Arty Doing a stable reverse sort by reversing before and after is also how Python's `sorted(reverse=True)` does it. [Quote](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5dcae3f0c3e9072251217e814a9438670e5f1e40/Objects/listobject.c#L2419-L2420): *"Reverse sort stability achieved by initially reversing the list, applying a stable forward sort, then reversing the final result."*

Comment: If the result is used for `a[s]`, then `len(a) - 1 - np.argsort(...` could instead be `~np.argsort(...` (i.e., use negative indices).

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of [`np.unique(..., return_inverse=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
u,tags = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
out = np.argsort(-tags, kind='stable')
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely simpler/faster solution than mine. Didn't know about `return_inverse` feature.

Answer (score 1):

One simplest solution would be through mapping sorted unique elements of any `dtype` to ascending integers and then stable ascending arg-sorting of negated integers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNCsIwGET3OcWAiyRQRa0uPUkp8rUNNmjTmB8wp4/RqriZgfeGsSmMs6lz1pOdXYCJk00gD2MZ4VRqQ85REg0nXoF3v@j/opUsLuNo9D0qQZLpBXhFrh99@VaDiBWKGZTvz/rxfb@8pFjrCldthkK5D9TdFJfMOm2C@OwlW@ENPJoaBxyxwx7bluX8BA)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'])
u = np.unique(a)
i = np.searchsorted(u, a)
desc_ix = np.argsort(-i, kind = 'stable')
print(desc_ix)
# prints [3 4 5 1 2 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @jdehesa's clean solution, this solution allows specifying an axis.

```py
indices = np.flip(
    np.argsort(np.flip(x, axis=axis), axis=axis, kind="stable"), axis=axis
)
normalised_axis = axis if axis >= 0 else x.ndim + axis
max_i = x.shape[normalised_axis] - 1
indices = max_i - indices
```